I want to obtain the score for each solving step for displaying it on the page
enter image description here
I saw this image on the official website. How can I get the score for each part? I tried using the content described in section 5.1 'Additional metrics' of the documentation and added the STEP_SCORE variable. However, the data I saw after monitoring was not the score for each step, but a final score. How can I obtain the score for each step? Can this only be done using benchmarking? I want to get the result of each step after solving is completed, similar to what's shown in this image

Take a look at the Micrometer section in the docs. IIRC it's possible to monitor the step scores.

Thanks for your reply! I read the Micrometer section and added the Metric in SolveConfig. However, accessing http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/timefold.solver.step.score.soft.score only gave me the final score, not a series of data.
To get the score via Java, I referred to the Benchmark code, added Metrics.addRegistry(statisticRegistry) and statisticRegistry.addListener, and finally got the data I needed from BestScoreStatisticPoint.

Note that BestScoreStatisticPoint is not public API and is subject to change at any point in time.

Thank you for the response. I will change my approach, what you said is very accurate.

The Timefold Solver documentation describes how to monitor the solver. Specifically, you're looking for the STEP_SCORE metric.
This will expose the metric using Micrometer, and you can consume the values using the standard Java observability API. Please do not use internal Timefold Solver classes to access the data - we do not provide backwards compatibility guarantees on classes outside of the API package.

Thank you for the response. I will change my approach, what you said is very accurate.
